# Why time field type is not visible in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, point, fields-attributes, timestamp

I have a roads.shp file which represents the highway map of Istanbul.

By using Random Extract tool, I generated 2000 random routes on the existing map. Then, I needed to add uniform generated points on those routes, once in 20 meters (done by using points along geometry from processing tools).

At last, I want to  add timestamp to each point, as if the points are the trajectories of the cars. To add the timestamp, I need to choose Time field type. The problem starts here: In the Field Calculator, the Time field type is not found, along with other so many field types. I tried to use Date field type but the result is not in the way I want. Can you help me about it? I use QGIS 3.22.2.

P.S. the CRS type I set my project is TUREF / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 10

[image: example]

Comment: You must use different spatial data format than shapefile. It doesn't support DateTime.

Comment: Thank you so much! data format is the issue. Which data format is recommended to use Time field type?

Comment: Geopackage. See the solution below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably use shapefiles to store your layer. To solve your issue, [save the layer to a Geopackage](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-a-new-geopackage-layer).

Shapefiles do not support Datetime field types. See the [QGIS documentation about Shapefiles](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-a-new-shapefile-layer):

> Only Decimal number, Whole number, Text data and Date attributes are
> supported.

See also [this explanation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/386013/88814).

Comment: For shapefiles I would refer to ESRI's documentation : https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi8y_PEobj1AhXbwQIHHXyhC6QQFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.esri.com%2Fcontent%2Fdam%2Fesrisites%2Fsitecore-archive%2FFiles%2FPdfs%2Flibrary%2Fwhitepapers%2Fpdfs%2Fshapefile.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3NpgIal6QykKc75RFQuPOD

Comment: OK, but I can't see any information about field types in this documentation - or did I overlook it? Searching for `text`, `string` or `date` does not find anything.

Comment: Search for *"Type"*

Comment: For `Type`, onle `Integer` and `Double` (and `Point`(?)) are mentioned - no information about `Date` or `Text/String`. Did the initial Shapefile format not have any corresponding fieldtypes?

Comment: I can be wrong, but it did not

Comment: OK, so this site here mentions field types including `Text` and `Date`: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012803